# Scroll view inside recyclerview item not working

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-nestedscrollview

I am using a Recycler view to show Some Card Views.
Each item of recycler view contains a long text.
I am trying to make that text scrollable.
I tried wrapping the text inside a Nested Scroll View.
But on swiping the item, the whole recycler view is scrolled, instead of the text inside the item.

simpler version of my recycler view item layout.

```
 <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            android:id="@+id/parent"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:onClick="@{()->viewHolder.navigateToDetails()}"
            android:paddingHorizontal="25dp"
            android:paddingVertical="15dp">

           <androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView
                android:id="@+id/crib_text_scroll_view"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                app:layout_constrainedHeight="true"
                app:layout_constraintHeight_max="300dp"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/category">
                
                <com.example.presentation.custom_views.ReadMoreTextView
                    android:id="@+id/crib_text"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                    app:mainText="@{cribResponse.post}"
                    tools:mainText="@tools:sample/lorem[20]" />

            </androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView>
 </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

layout of the fragment that contains recycler view

```
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <androidx.swiperefreshlayout.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
            android:id="@+id/swipe_refresh_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
                android:id="@+id/crib_rv"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:nestedScrollingEnabled="true"
             app:layoutManager="androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager"
                tools:listitem="@layout/item_text_crib" />

        </androidx.swiperefreshlayout.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>
    </androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Adapter class

```
class CribAdapter(private val rvHost: RVHost) :
    PagingDataAdapter<CribResponse, CribViewHolder>(diffCallback) {
    private val allAudioViewHolders: MutableList<AudioCribViewHolder> = mutableListOf()
    var playingViewHolder: AudioCribViewHolder? = null

    companion object {
        val diffCallback = object : DiffUtil.ItemCallback<CribResponse>() {
            override fun areItemsTheSame(oldItem: CribResponse, newItem: CribResponse): Boolean {
                return oldItem == newItem
            }

            override fun areContentsTheSame(oldItem: CribResponse, newItem: CribResponse): Boolean {
                return oldItem.postId == newItem.postId
            }
        }
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: CribViewHolder, position: Int) {
        val item = getItem(position)
        item ?: return
        holder.bind(item)
    }

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): CribViewHolder {
        return if (viewType == AUDIO_CRIB) {
            AudioCribViewHolder(parent = parent, RVHost = rvHost).apply {
                markCreated()
                allAudioViewHolders.add(this)
            }
        } else {
            TextCribViewHolder(parent = parent, rvHost = rvHost)
        }
    }

    override fun getItemViewType(position: Int): Int {
        val item = getItem(position)
        val audio = item?.postAudio
        return if (audio == null) TEXT_CRIB else AUDIO_CRIB
    }

    override fun onViewAttachedToWindow(holder: CribViewHolder) {
        super.onViewAttachedToWindow(holder)
        if (holder is AudioCribViewHolder) {
            holder.markAttach()
        }
    }

    override fun onViewDetachedFromWindow(holder: CribViewHolder) {
        super.onViewDetachedFromWindow(holder)
        if (holder is AudioCribViewHolder) {
            val isPlaying = holder.playing.value ?: false
            if (isPlaying) {
                holder.resetUI()
                playingViewHolder = null
                rvHost.stop()
            }
            holder.markDetach()
        }
    }

    fun selfLifecycleDestroyed() {
        allAudioViewHolders.forEach {
            it.markDestroyed()
        }
    }

    fun getCrib(position: Int): CribResponse? {
        return getItem(position)
    }
}
```

Comment: Add the code of your adapter file and your main java class file.

Comment: @youcantseeme i have added the adapter class and layout for my fragment. In the fragment kotlin class I am not doing any thing with the recycler view except setting adapter to recycler view and passing paging data to adapter

Comment: try wrapping your recycler view in NestedScrollView

Comment: @unownsp didn't work :-(